# Can this thing be built? Circuit to Increase 12vdc Rise Time Circuit (car-lighting)

Tags: circuit-analysis

I'm not a professional electronics engineer.  Just an auto-enthusiast.

I have no where to turn to ask if something like this old patent can be built by someone who knows electronics.

Does the info in the patent give precise directions to build this device or is there circuit info omitted to prevent it from being built?

THIS IS RELEVANT ONLY for cars that use non-LED brake-lights: any 2000's and older/vintage or classic cars that used incandescent bulbs, that are also retrofitted with hi-output incandescent bulbs which would increase the lag-time in bulb luminosity.

Here's the Patent and all the info, and I would appreciate your professional expertise if this can be built based on the info/schematics and description:

It's called a "Vehicle Stop Lamp System"
Inventors:  Michael J. Flannagan & Michael Sivak
Patent#  4,791,399
Date:  Dec. 13, 1988
https://pdfpiw.uspto.gov/.piw?PageNum=0&docid=04791399

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: It't not an exact recipe, but from the information in the patent I'm pretty sure the device can be constructed. I'm not sure the invention has any relevance in modern cars.

Comment: I would say such a system can be build. However, I doubt if the decrease in lag time is such that it is worth constructing such a complex system for. Something similar can be done using a resistor across the switch (the switch that switches the brake light) to make the lamp's filament stay hot. This wastes power but that might not be an issue. Also note that the fact that there is a patent doesn't mean it is a good and practical idea. Do any cars (from the past) have this system? I doubt it but feel free to prove me wrong.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Yes, and I would add that it is easier to patent a bad idea than a good idea, because no one else has tried to patent the bad ideas.

Comment: Switch to LED replacement bulbs (e.g., anything [like this one](https://www.sylvania-automotive.com/products/interior-and-exterior-bulbs/zevo-led/1157_zevo.jsp)), then if necessary address any problems with the blinker, with ballast resistors or an aftermarket blinker.  It'll be way cheaper, and you'll be on the road sooner.

Answer (score 3):

From a quick perusal, there is adequate information given for someone with ordinary (not exceptional) "skill in the art" to complete the design of a practical circuit and build it. That is the standard for patents. They are not intended to give exact instructions, and the exact parameters of the optimal design might be a bit different from what is in the patent.

Comment: Indeed, too much clarity in the instructions tends to be seen as a defect in patents!